# Hex String to Integer in Legacy SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

So I can do this

```
SELECT
  INTEGER(0xdae3a1)
```

But I cannot do this?

```
SELECT
  INTEGER('0xdae3a1')
```

WHY? How am I supposed to do this for a string column??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How am I supposed to do this for a string column??

Use below instead

```
#legacySQL
SELECT INTEGER(FLOAT('0xdae3a1'))
```

> WHY?

I guess it is a bug

Comment: Thanks @mikhail-berlyant :)